# Using ConfigService inside async provider nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to know if it possible to inject `ConfigService` into module import:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileService } from './file.service';
import { FileResolver } from './file.resolver';
import { FileUploadController } from './contollers/file-upload.controller';
import { S3Service } from './host/s3.service';
import { AwsSdkModule } from 'nest-aws-sdk';
import { S3, SharedIniFileCredentials } from 'aws-sdk';

@Module({
  controllers: [FileUploadController],
  providers: [FileService, FileResolver, S3Service],
  exports: [FileService, FileResolver],
  imports: [
    ConfigService.forRoot(),
    AwsSdkModule.forRoot({
     // use config service here
     // configService.get('some-value')
      defaultServiceOptions: {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: new SharedIniFileCredentials({
          profile: 'my-profile',
        }),
      },
      services: [S3],
    }),
  ],
})
export class StorageModule {}
```

is it possible to use the configService inside AwsSdkModule provider?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

```
AwsSdkModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigService], 
  inject: [ConfigService], 
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) {
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
AwsSdkModule.forRootAsync({
  defaultServiceOptions: {
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
      region: configService.get('region'),
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: configService.get('access_key'),
        secretAccessKey: configService.get('secret_key'),
      },
    }),
  },
  services: [S3],
})
```